# How to observe change of value and show it? In Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a variable that takes the number of objects in the array in a different class, how can I keep track of the change of this variable in the current class? I did a lot of different attempts but failed.

```
var digitIndex: Int! {
        set {
            self.digitIndex = newValue
        }
        get {
            return firstClass.indexesOfSelectedNodes().count
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if context == &digitIndex {
            if let newValue = change?[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] {
                print("newValue")
                infoLabel.text = "\(newValue)"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) in your code

```
var digitIndex: Int! {
        set {
            self.digitIndex = newValue
        }
        get {
            return firstClass.indexesOfSelectedNodes().count
        }
    }
```

digitIndex is computed property! You are not able to set self.digitIndex within its own setter!

this code, even though compiled, will run forever :-)

```
var i: Int {
    get {
        return 10
    }
    set {
        i = newValue
    }
}

i = 100
print(i)
```

2) How to use willSet and didSet (for STORED properties)?

```
class C1 {}
class C2 {}

class C {
    var objects: [AnyObject] = [C1(),C1(),C2()] {
        willSet {
            print(objects, objects.count, newValue)
        }
        didSet {
            print(objects, objects.count)
        }
    }
    func add(object: AnyObject) {
        objects.append(object)
    }
}

let c = C()
c.add(C1())
/*
[C1, C1, C2] 3 [C1, C1, C2, C1]
[C1, C1, C2, C1] 4
*/

var i: Int = 0 {
willSet {
    print(newValue, "will replace", i)
}
didSet {
    print(oldValue, "was replaced by", i)
}
}

i = 100
/*
100 will replace 0
0 was replaced by 100
*/
```

you could combine the computed and stored properties for your advantage

```
// 'private' storage
var _j:Int = 0
var j: Int {
get {
    return _j
}
set {
    print(newValue)
    if newValue < 300 {
    _j = newValue
    } else {
        print(newValue, "refused")
    }
}
}

print(j) // prints 0
j = 200  // prints 200
print(j) // prints 200
j = 500  // prints 500 refused
print(j) // prints 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var digitIndex: Int! {
        set {
            self.digitIndex = newValue
        }
        get {
            return firstClass.indexesOfSelectedNodes().count
        }
        didSet {
            //you will get new value here
        }
    }
```

No need to add observer for our class properties, you just required to add observer for the properties provided by super class.

Comment: did you try this? try it first, before answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a delegate handling the communication between your two classes.

An example follows below, using a custom delegate `MyDelegate` (protocol). A delegate instance is initialized in `MyOtherClass` (e.g., a view controller class), which makes a delegate callback whenever the array `myArr` is updated in this class. This, in turn, updates the value of `digitIndex` in `MyCurrentClass` (e.g., some custom control), which conforms to `MyDelegate` by implementing the blueprinted `arrUpdated(..)` method. Finally, the `didSet` property observer on `digitIndex` in `MyCurrentClass` tells us via console print-out that its value has been updated.

```
protocol MyDelegate: class {
    func arrUpdated(arr: [Int])
}

class MyDifferentClass {
    private var myArr : [Int] = [] {
        didSet {

            // Call delegate.
            delegate?.arrUpdated(myArr)
        }
    }

    weak var delegate: MyDelegate?
}

class MyCurrentClass: MyDelegate {
    var myDifferentClass : MyDifferentClass
    var digitIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("digitIndex updated: \(digitIndex)")
        }
    }

    init(a: MyDifferentClass) {
        myDifferentClass = a
        myDifferentClass.delegate = self
    }

    // MyDelegate
    func arrUpdated(arr: [Int]) {
        digitIndex = arr.count
    }
}
```

Test:

```
var a = MyDifferentClass()
var b = MyCurrentClass(a: a)

a.myArr.append(1) // prints 'digitIndex updated: 1'
```