# Access viewController from external file

Tags: ios, swift, class, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

Hi I am developing an app using swift.

This app has an MKMapView in the only viewController. I implemented a custom class file for mkannotation clustering. The annotation cluster has some buttons in it. Those buttons trigger a function that is inside the cluster class file. How can I get this function to trigger an action in the viewController?

Or to put it simply:

How can I access (and trigger a function in) a ViewController from an external swift file?

Comment: The general approach would be to pass a reference to your view controller to the object that wants to the object that needs to invoke the view controller's method.  If you search for delegate patterns, you'll see a few thousand examples.  (Also see `NSNotification` as another option.)

Comment: Somewhat as Phillip writes; use a delegate to an instance of your custom class file (in your view controller), and if some property in the custom class instance is updated, do a delegate callback to the view controller (which conforms to the protocol which is used as delegate in the custom class). See e.g. [the following answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34768446/4573247) for an example.

Comment: Just as others said, you can use delegate. One thing to remind is you usually need to set the delegate property in mkannotation class to be weak to avoid retain cycle. And the other way you can use to pass the information is NSNotificationCenter.

Answer (score 0):

this base  for view controller

var firstScene: UIWindowScene
var firstWindwos: UIWindow = UIWindow()
var controller: UIViewController!

```
init(){
    self.firstScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as! UIWindowScene
    
    if let window = firstScene.windows.first{
        firstWindwos = window
    }
    
    if let vc = firstWindwos.rootViewController {
        controller = vc as! ViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: only worked for viewcontroller